# setting onclick image for image button in android

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-button

I have a image button for which I have loaded a image in my XML using android:src tag.
I have few questions based on image button :

1. my image is resized for aspect ratio 130:51 but when I set my image button width and height to wrap_content I see image is loaded as crop I want it to full fit into the image button so that the spacing should not be visible.
2. when I run the app and tap on the image button I want a feel of state change. But currently I see it looks like a static image and when I tap it really doesn't show the push state changes. To achieve I want to load another image when user does tap event so he can see the state change and feel that button is clicked.

please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

save this XML as any name you want.

and then just set background of button with this XML. so this will change the images as per given states.

Comment: please also let me know how to set scale factor for image so that it should completely fit the imagebutton.

Comment: use android:scaletype in the image view xml

Comment: You can do as @shreyas has said. and also you can do programmatically image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

Comment: I tried scaletype = fitXY, center etc. but None of them worked correctly like how i wanted

Comment: try using button instead of imagebutton.

Answer (score 0):

1) `my_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

2)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_cab_done_pressed_example" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_cab_done_focused_example" />
        <item android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_cab_done_default_example" />
    </selector>
```